# Unused argument in GA package

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to use TSP package with GA. I want to do something similar to [this](http://rpubs.com/somasdhavala/GAeg)
My code:

```
library(GA)
library(globalOptTests)
library(TSP)

data("USCA50")

fitFun <-
  function(x)
   -tour_length(solve_TSP(USCA50))

dist <- as.matrix(USCA50)

GA <- ga(
  type = "permutation",
  fitness = fitFun,
  distMatrix = dist,
  min =1,
  max = 50
)
```

The error I get:

> Error in fitness(Pop[i, ], ...) : 
>     unused argument (distMatrix = c(0, 1167, 1579, 437, 3575, 1453, 226, 2976, 1107, 1006, 1046, 891, 1488, 1030, 1803, 190, 1122, 1373, 1860, 523, 1047, 1152, 370, 1453, 1629, 1323, 1032, 654, 1462, 752, 993, 813, 1178, 1705, 816, 1206, 1285, 1641, 1578, 1703, 1343, 1317, 1647, 1157, 1479, 1703, 1166, 1211, 795, 1572, 1167, 0, 413, 1422, 2895, 316, 1172, 3094, 140, 382, 189, 530, 392, 526, 635, 1174, 2056, 286, 692, 910, 207, 211, 1035, 303, 2046, 2164, 1385, 845, 297, 597, 1033, 393, 1766, 546, 386, 1076, 
>   153, 476, 432, 546, 184, 184, 481, 1579, 1686, 543, 20, 2008, 527, 434, 1579, 413, 0, 1832, 2766, 167, 1585, 3265, 508, 677, 547, 842, 229, 775, 229, 1575, 2451, 275, 289, 1277, 582, 514, 1420, 207, 2347, 2544, 1720, 1189, 116, 947, 1350, 800, 2117, 138, 777, 1338, 334, 62, 106, 145, 260, 312, 128, 1911, 1961, 136, 413, 2384, 913, 131, 437, 1422, 1832, 0, 3437, 1732, 272, 2607, 1327, 1355, 1345, 1269, 1787, 1409, 2041, 615, 697, 1670, 2093, 954, 1256, 1345, 807, 1672, 1242, 8

Is there something wrong with my GA package? RStudio doesn't show me this parameter but somehow others are able to run it.

Comment: That is because the function `ga` does not have an argument called `distMatrix`.    If you remove that,  you will still have a problem because `ga` also does not have arguments called `max` or `min`.   You can see the available arguments on the help page `?ga`

Comment: You are partly right. It does not have an argument `distMatrix` but `max` and `min` are required arguments. Without `max` or `min` it won't work. My problem is - how is it possible that in the code that I attached (http://rpubs.com/somasdhavala/GAeg) someone is able to use that argument.